# how to make flutter video player responsive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I was trying to make a webpage with a default video playing but in full screen [image: like this] it looks fine but when changing size it getting worst. Like this image how to fix this issue [image: like this]

```
class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {

VideoPlayerController? _videoCOntroller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
  _videoCOntroller!.initialize().then((value) {
  _videoCOntroller!.play();
  _videoCOntroller!.setLooping(true);
});
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              child: Container(
                height: size.height,
                width: size.width,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoCOntroller!),
              ),
            ),
          
          ),
          Positioned(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            child: 
                child:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using stack inside a column just removing that could fic the issue

Answer (score 2):

You set size.width to height of Container instead of size.height:

```
          child: Container(
            height: size.width,
            width: size.width,
            child: VideoPlayer(_videoCOntroller!),
          ),
```

And if changing that doesn't solve your problem. Change BoxFit.cover to BoxFit.fill.

**Edit 1:** I think this is a bug. The issue about Android will be solved with video_player 2.1.6 but I don't know the situation of web. You may want to checkout [this issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42945)

Comment: i do both of it and no change at all